# Set up MX records in apache/Ubuntu to point to external mail server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, mx

I have set up a virtual host on my Ubuntu server with apache2, and that all works fine when I change the nameservers, but how/where do I set the MX record to use the existing mail server (at 123-reg). i.e. I want the wesite to be hosted on my server but the mail to stay where it is.